# How do you use different databases with Rails, depending not on the model but on the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to Rails use database A or database B, both the exact same schema, depending on the the identity of the logged in user.

So to be clear, my problem is not the same as the one solved here:

http://weare.buildingsky.net/2006/12/06/multiple-concurrent-database-connections-with-activerecord

I'd like to use the same exact models, but a different databases, depending on who is logged in. Is this easy to do?

Comment: you might write a before filer that will open new connection with `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` method

Comment: That's what I'm trying, and it seems to work. Can I safely change Rails.env in a before_filter too?

Comment: OK changing Rails.env works but doesn't seem to be safe, since the effect lasts beyond the request

Comment: Did you try to change it in `after_filter`?

Comment: I suggest not messing with Rails.env - it feels dangerous. Bohdan's suggestion of using before_filter looks like a good answer. You have my +1 ;-)